# Value of type 'AVCapturePhotoOutput' has no member 'outputSettings'

Tags: swift, ios11, swift4

Curious, what would this be in Swift 4? 

`stimageout = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
stimageout?.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecJPEG]`

Currently, it errors with `Value of type 'AVCapturePhotoOutput' has no member 'outputSettings'` which is odd since I don't have memory of Apple changing this.

This is not "begging for help"-type question. I'm just curious if Apple changed this and the steps I need to do in order to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is `outputSettings` is a property on `AVCaptureStillImageOutput`, not `AVCapturePhotoOutput`.

`AVCaptureStillImageOutput` is deprecated in iOS 10, so for iOS 10+, use `AVCapturePhotoOutput` instead. To set settings using the new API, you can use an `AVCapturePhotoSettings` object.

```
let stimageout = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
settings.livePhotoVideoCodecType = .jpeg
stimageout.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self)
```

Apple's `AVCapturePhotoOutput` Documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturephotooutput